# Is is possible to use both Spring Web MVC and Spring Reactive Web in the same application?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflux

Currently I have already had a application that run with Spring Web MVC (Spring 4) for a long time (others thing like Spring Data, Spring Security, etc also mainly based on Spring 4).

Recently, I had an idea to migrate to Spring 5 using reactive web framework. However, I cannot migrate all of things in one day, I have to migrate gradually. I want to keep some of APIs that used traditional MVC, and the others use reactive web. Therefore, I want to ask people that have been in that context may share your own thought.

Comment: AFAIK, no. If you enable both, an MVC web server will be started by default, and you'll be able to use a reactive WebClient. Or you can choose to use WebFlux by calling SpringApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE). But not both. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-webflux. I wonder why, though, since WebFlux can run on Tomcat or Jetty too, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes. I will disable Tomcat and Jetty and use Netty instead. However, I wonder that if Web MVC goes well with Netty ?

Comment: No. MVC is based on the servlet spec, which Netty doesn't support. That's why WebFlux would need to run on Tomcat or Jetty if you also need MVC. But again, AFAIK, you cannot have both. Read my comment again, carefully.